# how to install Bitcoin and bitcoin cash on the same ubuntu server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, installation

I've installed bitcoin core as the documentation in bitcoin.org and its working great. then, I tried to install bitcoin-ABC manually as following:

1. `wget bitcoin-cash-gnu.tar.gz`
2. `tar xzf bitcoin-cash-gnu.tar.gz`
3. `cd bitcoin-cash-gnu/bin`
4. `ls`

> bitcoin-cli  bitcoin-qt  bitcoin-tx  bitcoind  test_bitcoin

5. I have renamed bin directory files so it doesn't conflict with bitcoin-legacy.

> bitcoinCash-cli  bitcoinCash-qt  bitcoinCash-tx  bitcoinCashd  test_bitcoinCash

6. then i've installed it on /etc/usr/bin

> sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-cash-gnu/bin/bin/*

Then I tried to run bitcoinCashd and

> Command not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to successfully install Bitcoin ABC on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, alongside Bitcoin Core, using these instructions:

1. Download the appropriate binary from here: https://download.bitcoinabc.org/

   For me, the command would be:

   `wget https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.16.2/linux/bitcoin-abc-0.16.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`
2. Extract the archive:

   `tar xzvf bitcoin-abc-0.16.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`
3. Rename the binary files:

   `cd bitcoin-abc-0.16.2/bin/; rename 's/bitcoin/bitcoinCash/' *`
4. Install the files into `/usr/local/bin`:

   `sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin *`

---

And voilà!

`bitcoinCashd -version` outputs:

> Bitcoin ABC Daemon version v0.16.2.0-6af5e93
>
> [...]

`bitcoind -version` outputs:

> Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.15.1
>
> [..]

`ls /usr/local/bin` outputs:

```
bitcoinCash-cli  bitcoinCash-seeder  bitcoind    test_bitcoin
bitcoinCashd     bitcoinCash-tx      bitcoin-qt  test_bitcoinCash
bitcoinCash-qt   bitcoin-cli         bitcoin-tx
```

Comment: I did exactly the same, but when I called bitcoinCashd it didn't work

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Your answer just gave me the chance to trust my solution and try again thanks!