# Run bitcoinCash on same server with bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I followed the great answer here [how to install bitcoin legacy and bitcoin cash on the same ubuntu server?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68522/how-to-install-bitcoin-legacy-and-bitcoin-cash-on-the-same-ubuntu-server/68576)

and installed bitcoinCash client to my ubuntu server.

Now I have both binaries available but they both work on same configs and same blockchains as I see.

[image]

There supposed be a way how to tell bitcoinCash client to download its own chain and use its own keys, but I cant figure out where those setup files for bitcoinCash are located and how to change them.

Could anyone help pls?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new username for Bitcoin cash or change default directory.

```
adduser BitcoinCashUser 

su BitcoinCashUser

BitcoinCashd -daemon
```

Now make sure it has own directory

```
cd ~/.bitcoin
```

You should find the files in here.

**Change Bitcoin Directory**

Follow these instructions on [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinABC/comments/6um84l/how_can_i_run_bitcoin_and_bitcoin_cash_on_the/?st=jdxn9tw2&sh=b27f1976)

Note: kill bitcoin-cash before start it again.

```
ps ax | grep bitcoinCashd
kill -9 <Process ID>
```