# Bitcoin & Bitcoin-cash in Ubuntu same server : Use same Block Data for both

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cash

**Configured Bitcoin server/rpc working good in Digital Ocean Ubuntu VPS.**
I also **want to set Bitcoin-Cash server parallel** in same server.

So **do I require to download all blocks of bitcoin-cash** node? because I already downloaded Bitcoin core blocks and BCC/BCC is forked from it. Your help could save my much BCC block sync time.

> I'm aware of setting BCC server independently. Just wan to know can we
>   use same downloaded blocks for BCC JSON-RPC?

Followed this link [how to install bitcoin legacy and bitcoin cash on the same ubuntu server?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68522/how-to-install-bitcoin-legacy-and-bitcoin-cash-on-the-same-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Resync blocks would be easier than splitting blocks

Comment: @Adam So firstly I have to set Bitcoin-ABC and after that Resync bitcoin block? or Recynce BCC block? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## So do I require to download all blocks of bitcoin-cash node?

Yes. Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash share a history, but only up to the fork.

Possibly you might be able to make yourself a `bootstrap.dat` up to the fork for Bitcoin Cash to load, depending on exactly what software you are running for each. There are accurate and working instructions for creating `bootstrap.dat` [linked in another recent question here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/42916/75001).

Comment: Can you please share any link, Thanks very much.

Comment: @VishalDalve I have added a link to the working instructions that I was referring to in my answer.

Comment: @oh, got it :-)